# Where can we find the source code of \thefigure?

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents

I was wondering where can we find the source code of `\thefigure`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually you will not find an explicit definition for `\thefigure`. It is implicitely defined by the command `\newcounter{figure}` usually in the class definition file, e.g. `article.cls`. However you can find also a redefinition for use in an appendix there, but this is not the main definition.

Comment: Is there a reason you're wanting the source code of `\thefigure`?

Comment: If you only want to see the applying definition: Use `\show\thefigure` to see the definition in the log and on the console.

Comment: Maybe you want to read through [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1) and linked questions. (if you want to modify it or making something similar, **do** read through it because TeX programming is highly counterintuitive.

Comment: There is `\meaning\thefigure` but it only shows the first few characters.